# apache python error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am getting this in my error log file. Ive been searching for asolution but have found nothing. I am trying to deploy django with mod_wsgi.

```
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117] ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_functools.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117] mod_wsgi (pid=20219): Target WSGI script '/home/dbs/public_html/test.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117] mod_wsgi (pid=20219): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/dbs/public_html/test.wsgi'.
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]   File "/home/dbs/public_html/test.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]   File "/home/dbs/sites/domain.com/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]     from threading import Lock
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 13, in <module>
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]     from functools import wraps
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/functools.py", line 10, in <module>
[Wed Jun 13 12:15:53 2012] [error] [client 207.46.13.117]     from _functools import partial, reduce
```

Comment: This would suggest you've installed a 64-bit python interpreter but kept the 32-bit _functools.so somehow.

Comment: Im using a shared library with a parallel python 2.6 installation with python 2.4

Comment: Trying to get Python 2.4 to use Python 2.6's standard library by messing with the PYTHONPATH seems like recipe for disaster even if they're both 32-bit or 64-bit; you're probably quite likely to see syntax errors as well.

Comment: both python installations are 64bit. What PYTHONPATH would i add to my .bash_profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong version of the `functional` module installed. Either install the correct binary version, or use the pure-python version.

Comment: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: can I just swap out _functools.so with the correct one in  /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload or would this break python?

Comment: @user1442957 You can try it, but I can't guarantee you won't see problems at some point. It would be much better to install a version compatible with your installation.